# How to implement SSO in android app

Tags: java, android

I have two different app,i have user database in backend,if any user loged in one app,he can also login in the another app without pressing login,just like facebook,how can i implement SSO in app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) also you can do the same using [Shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Using Shared preferences here is the example:
Call this method when user logged in one app.

```
   public void writeSSOInfo(){
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CheckSSO",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
         if(userLoggedIn){
            editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
            }else{
           editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
              }
            editor.commit();
        }
```

After saving in shared memory you can access the same detail in another application using below method.

```
public void readSSOInfo(){
  Context con;
     try {
         con = createPackageContext("com.app.packagename1", 0);
         SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences("CheckSSO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         dataShared = pref.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: but it can be a security issue... @Madhukar

Comment: unless some one comes to know the exact Package name and shared key. Shared key can be encrypt/decrypt using md5 algorithm which i have used.

Comment: there is something called keychain...is there any implementation link?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be after you logged in with any of the apps, I would store a user token with in SharedPreferences between both apps. Then get it at onCreate method of the both apps like this:

```
String PACKAGE_NAME = "your.package";
String PREFERENCE_NAME = "user-token";
String USER_TOKEN = "";

try {
        myContext = createPackageContext(PACKAGE_NAME,Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);             
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
        USER_TOKEN = sharedPrefs.getString(PREFERENCE_NAME, "");
        }
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {     
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then check if USER_TOKEN is empty or not and if it is not I would skip to next screen and keep using same Auth token.